# Web Browser in a Java Application

Tags: java

How can I open a webpage from a java application and enter username and password into it? I have seen questions here where people have referred to lobo or DJ Native Swing.

But as I am very new to java these libraries seem quite complex to me and I can not find a good tutorial in it, please refer to some good library with a solid tutorial which can be a beginning ground for me.

Note: I am developing a Java Swing application and show the user a page opening and user name and password being submitted.

Comment: Do you really need a browser? isn't just a client enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748895/how-do-you-open-web-pages-in-java I think it is duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What application do you develop? Web? Desktop/swing? Console? Mobile?

Comment: I am developing a swing application .

Comment: Do you want to open this page inside your app or new browser window?

Comment: Inside my app ..is best for me.As i have to put some data from the application to a webpage after login, it is like submitting another form after login..

Comment: Use SWTBroweser or mozswing. You can access page dom model and modify it in both cases AFAIK

Comment: Mozswing seems good to me, but is their a tutorial for it. I have google but could not find a simple tutorial..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache's [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) project

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do.

1) Do you want to show it to the user? 
join to [WebKit browser in Java app on multiple platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279337/webkit-browser-in-java-app-on-multiple-platforms)

2) You want to fetch some data from a web page that requires login?
then you should join to [HttpClient login, search and get the XML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057701/httpclient-login-search-and-get-the-xml-content)

Comment: I want to show it to user. i.e he should see a page opening, login information being filled in the form and login button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, are you trying to write a java application that will open a browser and enter data automatically?

If this is what you want then you can use selenium, a plugin for Mozilla. You can record your mouse movements, all your actions will get recorded as a jUnit test case.

You can then modify this junit test and read in the usernanme and password programatically from a file (or what ever you are trying to do.). This test can be run as a stand alone java application.

Comment: What is not clear in the question ? I can not use selenium as i have to perform other functions also, so an independent application is a complete no no !